# Не вносятся данные в БД. C#, WinForm

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Делаю windows form связанную с БД xampp my sql, чтобы в форме можно было заполнять базу данных
Выдает ошибку в строе if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)

Исключение не обработано
System.InvalidOperationException: "Connection must be valid and open."

Помогите пожалуйста

```
internal class DB
        {
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;database=shop1;");
            public void openConnection()
            {
                if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();
            }
            public void closeConnection()
            {
                if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                    connection.Close();
            }

            public MySqlConnection getConnection()
            {
                return connection;
            }

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DB db = new DB();
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO products (name, price) VALUES('@name', '@price')");


            command.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@price", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;

            db.openConnection();
            if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                MessageBox.Show("Товар добавлен");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Товар не добавлен");

            db.closeConnection();

        }
```

Comment: В строке подключения нет пароля

Comment: БД у меня без пароля

Comment: А что за метка, Alexander ?

Comment: Имена sql-параметров не нужно брать в кавычки: `VALUES(@name, @price)`

Comment: `name` - ключевое/зарезервированное слово. Имя колонки с таким названием следует заключать в кавычки: `products (\`name\`, price)`

Comment: MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO products ('name', 'price') VALUES(@name, @price", db.getConnection());

В таком формате правильно ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вы создаете

```cs
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("текст запроса");
```

А как команда поймет, какое подключение к базе надо использовать, чтобы принести вам данные? Телепатически? :)

То есть ей надо назначить подключение. У вас даже метод есть `getConnection()`, вы не находите странным, что ни разу его не использовали?

```cs
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("текст запроса", db.getConnection());
```

Comment: Вот я балда, соглашусь
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"
Но теперь он выдает данную ошибку, насколько я понял связанную с синтаксисом базы данных

Comment: @ТимурИжгузин `'@name', '@price'` апострофы уберите. Если ответ был полезен, вы можете принять его, поставив зеленую галочку слева от ответа.

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: "Connection must be valid and open."

MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO products ('name', 'price') VALUES(@name, @price"); db.getConnection();

Все также ссылается на строку if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)

Comment: @ТимурИжгузин у вас `db.getConnection()` за скобку вывалился. `new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO products ('name', 'price') VALUES(@name, @price)", db.getConnection());`. Я ж не буду вам каждую запятую отлаживать, да ведь? :)

Comment: Я и так и так пробовал, если вставлять как вы написали

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''name', 'price') VALUES('123', '123')' at line 1"

Comment: @ТимурИжгузин это разве значит что мой ответ неверный? Ошибка с соединением устранена? Ваш вопрос про нее был. ``INSERT INTO products (`name`, `price`) VALUES(@name, @price)``

Comment: Нет не значит, спасибо за ваш ответ многоуважаемый.